# Java ResultSet close error sqlite3

Tags: java, sqlite

Пишу БД sqlite3 на java через драйвер jdbc, имею следующий код:

```java
ResultSet resultSet = DatabaseConnect.DB.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Player_kits WHERE player = '" + player.getName() +"' AND slot = '" + KitEditor.map.get(player.getName()) + "'");
   System.out.println(resultSet.getString("player"));
   System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("slot"));
```

Конкретно в подробности не вдавайтесь, ошибка конкретно в строках sout(resultset.get), так как после того как я убрал их из своего кода ошибка исчезла. Почитал другие статьи на stackoverflow, но в общем-то ничего не получилось.

Ну и стактрейс ошибки + ошибка:

```java
[19:33:02 INFO]: ledl123 issued server command: /kiteditor_join 3
[19:33:03 INFO]: ResultSet closed
[19:33:03 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:76)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:39)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:444)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at justiks.kiteditor.command.TemporaryClass.lambda$onCommand$1(TemporaryClass.java:26)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:101)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:54)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at com.destroystokyo.paper.ServerSchedulerReportingWrapper.run(ServerSchedulerReportingWrapper.java:22)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[19:33:03 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[19:33:03 INFO]: error
```

где error message 2 строка
стактрейс всё остальное

Comment: Ошибка сообщает, что у вас закрытый ResultSet, возможно, результат запроса возвращает пустое множество строк.

Comment: Там разве не нужно вызывать `ResultSet.next()` перед чтением данных? В `ResultSet` же в общем случае много строк, его нужно спозиционировать на конкретную строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был прост: я не корректно прописал путь к jdbc драйверу...